# Where to find geckodriver needed by Selenium Python package?

Tags: apt, python

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Executing `python -V` returns `Python 2.7.12`. I am building a virtualenv off of that so as to install the [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) package into it via:

```
pip install -upgrade selenium
```

But when doing a trial run with the following python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

it results this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/myuser/bin/selenium-experiment.py", line 2, in <module>
     browser = webdriver.Firefox()
   File "/home/myuser/python_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
     self.service.start()
   File "/home/myuser/python_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

 Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f782c1caa50>> ignored
```

Since `geckodriver` is an executable, I concluded that it should be provided by the installation of the selenium package via `pip` or at least error out with some message stating what I need to do next. Apparently not, so I dug further: I thought that perhaps Ubuntu should have a package that provides the `geckodriver` executable so I used `apt-file search geckodriver` to search for it and found no results.

Where do I get this `geckodriver` executable?

Comment: Get it from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver.

Comment: Why can't pip install command for selenium  just install whatever selenium depends upon?

Comment: That's a question for maintainers of Selenium and geckodriver. All I can say is you do have to get geckodriver from somewhere (GitHub in this case) other than PyPI.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Find the [latest release](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for your OS.

Extract it, and copy geckodriver to `/usr/local/bin` -- so if `v0.11.1` was the most recent version, and you were on 64bit linux, you'd do this:

```
export GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION='v0.24.0'
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION/geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz
rm geckodriver-$GECKO_DRIVER_VERSION-linux64.tar.gz
chmod +x geckodriver
cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Now your trial run should work.

Comment: Same method applies for chromedriver as well. :)

Comment: chromedriver can now be installed with `apt-get install -qqy chromedriver`.

Comment: If this doesn't work, copy the gecko driver to `/usr/bin`. This worked for me

Comment: `cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/` needs SUDO permission. So Sudo it.

Answer (score 16):

Ubuntu 16.04+:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver
```

Comment: No longer seems to be available as of Ubuntu 22.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/web/firefox-geckodriver