# How can I install and set up Selenium WebDriver on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, selenium

What should I do in order to install [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?

Comment: [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) is a testing framework for web applications. You basically automate interactions with the app in the browser and check whether the expected results occur - for example, "if I click on the link that says *edit*, an textbox with this id should be inserted". Typically, you create many such tests and run them automatically to check whether changes broke something. [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) is a tool from this framework.

Comment: Follow the steps given in this link: https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-chromedriver-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5):

The below info were taken from: [Python - Getting Started With Selenium WebDriver on Ubuntu/Debian](https://dzone.com/articles/python-getting-started)

WebDriver (part of Selenium 2) is a library for automating browsers, and can be used from a variety of language bindings. It allows you to programmatically drive a browser and interact with web elements. It is most often used for test automation, but can be adapted to a variety of web scraping or automation tasks.

To use the WebDriver API in Python, you must first install the Selenium Python bindings. This will give you access to your browser from Python code. The easiest way to install the bindings is via pip.

On Ubuntu/Debian systems, this will install pip (and dependencies) and then install the Selenium Python bindings from PyPI:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

After the installation, the following code should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

This should open a Firefox browser sessions and navigate to http://www.ubuntu.com/

Here is a simple functional test in Python, using Selenium WebDriver and the unittest framework:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class TestUbuntuHomepage(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def testTitle(self):
        self.browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
        self.assertIn('Ubuntu', self.browser.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Output:

```
testTitle (__main__.TestUbuntuHomepage) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.931s

OK
```

Comment: What about geckodriver?

Answer (score 3):

Install latest google-chrome webdriver for Python-selenium binding:

```
$ LATEST=$(wget -q -O - http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
$ wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST/chromedriver_linux64.zip
$ unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && sudo ln -s $PWD/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Try below Example to open 'http://www.ubuntu.com/' in google-chrome browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

Following is the link for Firefox-webdriver: 
[Install Firefox web-driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851401/where-to-find-geckodriver-needed-by-selenium-python-package)

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to update the path, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

- On Unix systems you can do the following to append it to your system’s search path, if you’re using a bash-compatible shell:

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/directory/of/executable/downloaded/in/previous/step
  ```
- On Windows you will need to update the Path system variable to add the full directory path to the executable geckodriver manually or command line(don't forget to restart your system after adding executable geckodriver into system PATH to take effect). The principle is the same as on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

- This File Working In Linux(Debian,Ubuntu,Kali Linux)
- This method is tested In Kali Linux
- This file is not working in Windows

**How To Install**

- Use Code In **Terminal Linux(Debian,Ubuntu,Kali Linux)**

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/khaled-dev-loper/webdriver-firefox-installer.git 
  cd webdriver-firefox-installer
  ```
- Download Your Webdriver From https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and extract `geckodriver` in `webdriver-firefox-installer` folder
- Run Python File:

  ```
  python3 installation.py
  ```

  or run Bash File

  ```
  chmod +x installation.sh
  ./installation.sh
  ```